# How to include Google Font in JSFiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle, webfonts, google-fonts

I'm trying to include a Google font in jsFiddle without success. I added the URL to "External Resources" but it is included as a `<script>`.

[image: Screenshot]

This is the font that I want to include:

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: You can also just add the `<link>` tag to the *html* section

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Webfonts must be included in the CSS quadrant, using @import:

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300);
```

Comment: It must be https instead of http in the url.

Comment: @Bula, the use of https is not required. However, y removed the protocol to let the browser decide the best one. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026809/google-web-fonts-on-https-pages-on-chrome

Comment: Remember to put the @import rule at the very top of your CSS page. Also check your console for errors that may be preventing a style from appearing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dataURL if you haven't got any url online(only available on local computer)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'us101';
  src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAASAQA...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

locate this line on your HTML page (or template):

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and change it to this:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This simple change will make your browser call the Google Font page in the applicable mode (HTTP vs HTTPS).

source: https://www.amixa.com/blog/2012/06/06/how-to-use-google-fonts-under-both-ssl-and-non-ssl-without-ssl-insecure-messages/