# Custom font (not using @font-face) won't load on HTTPS protocol

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, custom-font

I am trying to fix an issue where my custom font (ArcaMojora) is not loading on HTTPS protocol and I have seen a ton of fixes everywhere for code that uses @font-face. After searching vigorously through my WP theme files I realized that my theme (Kleanity) doesn't use @font-face at all but rather below code.

How can I adjust the code so that the custom font loads with HTTPS as well as HTTP?

Any and all help appreciated!

```css
 // add filter to register custom fonts for font lists 
 add_filter('gdlr_core_custom_uploaded_font', 'kleanity_register_custom_uploaded_font');
 if( !function_exists('kleanity_register_custom_uploaded_font') ){
  function kleanity_register_custom_uploaded_font( $custom_fonts ){

   $custom_font = kleanity_get_option('typography', 'font-upload');
   if( !empty($custom_font) ){
    foreach($custom_font as $font_option){
     $custom_fonts[$font_option['name']] = array(
      'eot' => $font_option['eot'],
      'ttf' => $font_option['ttf'],
     );
    }
   }

   $custom_fonts['ArcaMojora'] = array(
    'name' => 'ArcaMojora',
    'eot' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/ArcaMajora/ArcaMajora3-Bold.eot',
    'ttf' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/ArcaMajora/ArcaMajora3-Bold.ttf',
    'font-weight' => 600
   );
   $custom_fonts['ArcaMojora-Heavy'] = array(
    'name' => 'ArcaMojora',
    'eot' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/ArcaMajora/ArcaMajora3-Heavy.eot',
    'ttf' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/ArcaMajora/ArcaMajora3-Heavy.ttf',
    'font-weight' => 800,
    'varient' => true
   );
   
   return $custom_fonts;
   
  } // kleanity_register_custom_uploaded_font
 } // function_exists
```

Comment: What error are you seeing in developer tools when you try to load the font over https?

Comment: None that I am aware of, but I am also not a developer unfortunately. What I see is that the custom font loads when I visit the website using http protocol but not with the https one, other than that everything works fine. It is the font in the "Let your brand speak its mind" headline:
HTTP: http://www.ayzwriting.com
HTTPS: https://www.ayzwriting.com

Comment: Here's it being blocked in the https version: https://imgur.com/wVjGglj. So the problem is that it's always trying to request the resource through http even when you're on the site as https. You can fix this by changing the path to use the relative protocol, like `//` instead of `http://` or `http://`, but that might mean you need to find where that is being requested. Seems to be the `get_template_directory_uri()` function.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/40161844/7920525

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I've located the URL from where it loads the font and replaced "http://" with just "//" in all places.

But the font still doesn't load with HTTPS protocol, and the error I get (6 times) is below. What to do?

jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.8:103 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.ayzwriting.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://www.ayzwriting.com/wp-content/themes/kleanity/fonts/ArcaMajora/ArcaMajora3-Bold.ttf'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: In the "font-upload" object where the URL was I also noticed that the URL for the fonts was ["\/\/demo.goodlayers.com\/kleanity\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/11\/ArcaMajora3-Bold.eot"] which is an outside source, so I tried replacing it with the URL to the files on my server ["\/\/ayzwriting.com\/wp-content\/themes\/kleanity\/fonts\/ArcaMajora\/ArcaMajora3-Bold.eot"] but this didn't solve the problem. It did, however reduce the number of errors from 6 to 4, so maybe I'm on the right path?

Comment: Cool. Did you check that page https://stackoverflow.com/a/40161844/7920525 ? Seems to be highly relevant to your problem.

Comment: Well, in the end it was @font-face all along, just hidden away in a file that my search tool wasn't reaching. Huge thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end it was @font-face all along, just hidden away in a file that my search tool wasn't reaching. Sorry about that and thanks for the help! Solution can be found here among other places: [Google Web Fonts on HTTPS pages on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026809/google-web-fonts-on-https-pages-on-chrome)